# Simple form submit with files

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs

I am trying to write a simple upload form with input file type using React JS. When i submit the file, it is not submitting multi form data. It is submitting plain input file name.

Do we need to make any other changes if we want to write upload functionality in React.

Basic javascript code for uploading ([js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeevprasanna/UdDsn/1/)) :

```
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>

                <form name="secret" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"  method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/uploadFile">
            Please choose two files to upload.
            <br/>
                File 1:<input type="file" id="profilePic" name="profilePic"/>             
            <br/> 
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
            </div>);
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<HelloMessage />, document.body);
```

Can someone help me to write using React JS.

Comment: What you have posted is HTML, not JavaScript.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i gave actual React JS code. Can you please have a look at this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Casing is important for React components. Try `encType` instead of `ENCTYPE`. (You should have seen a warning in your console suggesting that you use `encType`.)

Here's a complete list of tags and attributes:[DOM Elements](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html).